# IP address mask in MFC property grid control

Tags: c++, mfc, maskedtextbox

I want to add a masked editbox in mfc propertygrid ctrl for IP address. According to definition

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty(const CString& strName, const COleVariant& varValue
              , LPCTSTR lpszDescr = NULL, DWORD_PTR dwData = 0
              , LPCTSTR lpszEditMask = NULL, LPCTSTR lpszEditTemplate = NULL
              , LPCTSTR lpszValidChars = NULL);
```

but I cant figure out the use of `lpszEditMask` and `lpszEditTemplate` in this context.I think I have to use the mask like *T("*._.***.***") but not sure what is the use of template. Another thing, How to ensure the input in each octet does not exceeds 255 .

Comment: I think this [link](http://ntcoder.com/bab/mfc-feature-pack-tutorial-part-3-cmfcpropertygridctrl/) will help you a little. This link shows how to create a masked edit control for phone number.

Comment: @CodeDreamer, sorry but I can't see any link .

Comment: [MFC Feature Pack Tutorial – Part 3 – CMFCPropertyGridCtrl](http://ntcoder.com/bab/mfc-feature-pack-tutorial-part-3-cmfcpropertygridctrl/)